# Insert multiple rows with Knex query

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // req.body = [1,2,3,4,5] (these are player ids)
  function createGame() {
      return knex.insert({'gameDate': new Date(), 'season_id': 1})
          .into('game') // creates new game with new id
          .returning('id') // return that new game id
      }
      .then(game_Id => {
          function createPlayerGameRow(game_id, req.body) { // req refer above
              req.body.forEach(id => {
                  return knex.insert({ 'player_id': id, 'game_id': game_id })
                     .into('player_game')
              })
          }
      })
})
```

This section of code has to separate queries in which the first query, createGame(), creates a new game in my game table. This works fine.

I am having a problem trying to chain another query (createPlayerGameRow()) in the promise of the first.

The function will fire and loop through the array of id's, but it will not insert new rows into my player_game table, as to signify that play 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are now able to record some stats.

I've look far and wide and have had no luck in figuring this out. I must be doing something wrong with looping the insert into the player_game table.

Comment: I am not sure of this, but is it OK to call then after the "}" ?!??
I think the correct way of doing this is to add the chain call to .returning(id)

Comment: Should just act like a promise statement. Without it, the logic would be asynchronous in nature.

Comment: Are you sure that chaining the then call to the returning won't solve the problem? I am not a JS expert and I didn't understand your answer but I think that will solve it

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: need to use Promise.all() to and mapped over the array of id's

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let player_ids = req.body.players
  queries.createGame()
    .then(game_id => {
      return Promise.all(player_ids.map(player_id => {
        return Promise.resolve(queries.createPlayerGame(game_id[0], player_id))
      }))
      .then(elem => {
        res.json({msgInside: elem})
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
       res.json({msgErr: err})
    })
})
```